# Create PeerConnection exception: Failed to construct 'RTCPeerConnection': Malformed RTCIceServer

Tags: node.js, webrtc, apprtc, rfc5766turnserver

I am using [appRTC to make](https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-node-server) demo app. I have setup following things successfully but got stack with JSON format that return in response of Turn-server API.

- Use SSL for secure connect to make it work on Google Chrome (Done)
- Implement custom WebSockets (Done)
- Develop custom API for TurnServer (Done)

I am getting following error in console log.

> Create PeerConnection exception: Failed to construct 'RTCPeerConnection': Malformed RTCIceServer
>
> Failed to start signaling: Cannot read property 'addStream' of null

I have tried following responses as **ice server object**

Current object:

```
{"iceServers":[{"urls":["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"]},{"urls":["turn:domain.com:8080?transport=udp","turn:domain.com:8080?transport=tcp","turn:domain.com:8080"],"username":"test","credential":"password"}],"lifetimeDuration":"86400s","blockStatus":"NOT_BLOCKED","iceTransportPolicy":"all"}
```

Have also tried:

```
[{"urls":["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"]},{"urls":["turn:domain.com:8080?transport=udp","turn:domain.com:8080?transport=tcp","turn:domain.com:8080"],"username":"test","credential":"password"}]
```

and also tried this one:

```
[{"urls":["turn:domain.com:8080?transport=udp","turn:domain.com:8080?transport=tcp","turn:domain.com:8080"],"username":"test","credential":"password"}]
```

Comment: how does ice server object look like? It should be an array of objects, each with a urls property and (in case of a turn url) username and credential

Comment: @PhilippHancke I have updated my answer. I have include the objects I have tried so far

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo here:

`[{"urls":["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"}`

trying to close urls without closing the array.
This should be

`[{"urls":["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"]}`

This doesn't result in an error about malformed RTCIceServer though.

Based on your comment it seems to be a result of calling

`new RTCPeerConnection({"iceServers":[{}]})`

-- an empty object is not a valid RTCIceServer.

I would also recommend not passing 

`"lifetimeDuration":"86400s","blockStatus":"NOT_BLOCKED"`

to the RTCPeerConnection as it doesn't know about these.

Comment: Sorry that typo was accrued when I paste my response here because I overwrite some values. I have updated my answer, Please have a look

Comment: Here is TURNSERVER API URL, I am using to get response. You can see real response from this [link](https://domaintools.ltd/turnserver-api/)

Comment: I have live the demo URL that I am testing, you can test this by your self, might be I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: you are calling "new RTCPeerConnection({"iceServers":[{}]})" somehow even though the http response looks correct. And an empty object is not a valid ice server

Comment: yes that's the problem. iceServers will not filled automatically by TURN HTTP request? Should I hard-code them?

Comment: hardcoding turn credentials is a very bad idea. It looks like your format is different from what apprtc expects, see the line in the source code that says
```
var turnServers = createIceServers(turnServerResponse.uris, turnServerResponse.username, turnServerResponse.password);
```
This looks like there is a mismatch between your apprtc version and the appr.tc one

Comment: Yes, I have notice the code available at GitHub repo is quit old. My `apprtc.debug.js` has 2000 lines of code but appr.tc have 5000+ lines of code at same file.

Comment: Can you please help me to sort the issue. I am stack with this from 3 days

Comment: I have hard-coded the values of IceServer config for testing purpose. But still getting same error + `Cannot create RTCPeerConnection; WebRTC is not supported by this browser.`